# TypeAhead not working on Remote URL

Tags: jquery, json, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js 0.11.1 to implement automcomplete functionality. 
JQuery version is 1.8.3

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       var engine = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: function (d) {d.communityName}, 
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          remote: {
              'cache': false,
              url: '/portal/vcm/instituteSearch/%QUERY',
              wildcard: '%QUERY'
          }
      });

    $('#schools-suggestion-box').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: false,
            minLength: 3,
            offset: false
        },
        {
            source: engine,
            displayKey : 'communityName',
            templates: {
                 empty:function(data){
                    return '<div class="empty-message">unable to find any school or university that match the current query</div>';
                 },
                suggestion: function(data){

                    return '<div class="school-suggestions">' + data.communityName + '</div>';
                } 
            }
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {        
            window.location.href=datum.sessionInitiator;
        });

//end document ready
```

I am facing the issue that all the results received from server is not populated on the UI. If there are 5 records coming from server only 3 records would be displayed on UI.

Another issue that if result was found starting with search character, then only that string will be displayed in the UI.

If I use local array everything is working fine in UI.

I had read that typeahead requires jquery version 1.9+ but I cannot switch to this version due to some dependecies.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to rewrite the portions that are 1.9+ dependencies, or use a different autocomplete plugin.

Comment: Thanks @dave. Just wanted to know why functionality working fine on local array but not properly working on remote URL ?